# Catalyst web application design question to do with template implementation

Tags: perl, catalyst

I'm just starting out with Catalyst and am still trying to wrap my head around it, so please bear with me.

I have to generate a table (HTML) of what amounts to links to specific database records.  The records span many database tables.  This table (HTML) should behave like a menu within the already defined wrapper template.  Clicking an element of this 'menu table' should load a page with the 'menu table' as well as the selected record contents below it (either for viewing or as a form for editing).

My thought is to use chained actions/methods to produce the content (straight forward enough).  Then use a single template (template toolkit) to determine if we display only the 'menu table, or the 'menu table' and a view of the selected record, or the 'menu table' and a form to edit the selected record.  So for example, the template would always produce the 'menu table', but depending on if it is being used by a FormFu action/method, it may or may not produce the form for editing the selected record.  So the template would have conditional code for displaying or editing records.

It almost feels like a template within a template type solution is required.  Can someone with Catalyst experience shed some light?  Maybe comment on whether or not I'm headed in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Template within a template.. i hear the js bell ring. Implement a json api that gives you what you need and load it via ajax (or more ajaj) reqeust.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the state of the objects when the server call is made (rather than on the client side), then you should be able to resolve this issue using the standard IF and BLOCK statement stuff available in template toolkit.  BLOCK will give you the template within a template (with variables) and IF-ELSE-END is also available.  Please see the documentation here:

http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html

However, if you only know client side, then Mugen in the comments is correct, if I were coding something like this on a short timeline, I would write the ajax page, then I would use jQuery clone against a template div to fill in the data and build the menus relatively quickly, after making the ajax call, of course:

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

But I can't be certain with the specs given, and without some code to look at.

Comment: Yes, thanks Horus.  I've tested using the PROCESS directive to load a a separate template file.  This will certainly improve what I was doing by modularizing my code to a greater degree.  I haven't written any functional JS yet (gone through some books).  From everything I've read I think I'd like to get to jquery as soon as possible.  Do you have any recommends on the best path considering my novice level?

Comment: No.  jQuery is a great way to learn javascript (though some would disagree).  The person who wrote jQuery (edit: originally said javascript) has written several high quality books.  Do a few Catalyst tutorials, and write a couple of simple applications.  Just learn by doing.  You are on the right path already.

Answer (score 1):

As Horus commented, giving you the best answer to this question depends a bit on whether the server side knows the state (view or edit) of the object in question.

Don't forget that TT offers you the ability to `INCLUDE` or `PROCESS` another template within an existing one. So assuming the server-side (and hence TT) knows the state of the object, something like this should be pretty straightforward:

```
WRAPPER "wrapper.tt";
PROCESS "menu.tt" IF is_menu;
SET tmpl = is_edit ? "edit" : "view";
PROCESS "$tmpl.tt";
```

You can keep things pretty DRY with that approach.

Comment: This looks like it might be the juice that I was looking for.  I still have to test it and fully wrap my head around it, but I guess it doesn't mind that the template these directives are in, are themselves within another WRAPPER template?

Comment: You can set the wrapper template in your view and never have to think about it.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason why this logic can't be in the WRAPPER itself. It makes perfect sense for the menu logic to be there. The decision on whether the main part of the page is the edit or view template seems like it should be server-side to me, but you know your app better than I.